# Can I safely use redis/kafka clients across go routines?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, redis, goroutine

I have this (incomplete) sample program using [go-redis](https://github.com/redis/go-redis):

```
func doThings(ctx context.Context, cache redis.Cache) {
  ..
  eventString, err := cache.GetDel(ctx, myKey).Result()
  ..
}

func doOtherThings(ctx context.Context, cache redis.Cache) {
  ..
  eventString, err := cache.GetDel(ctx, myKey).Result()
  ..
}

func main() {
  ctx := context.Background()

  cache := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr:     redisHost,
    Password: "",            // no password set
    DB:       redisDatabase, // use default DB
  })

  go doThings(ctx, *cache)
  go doOtherThings(ctx, *cache)
}
```

Is there any issue creating one Client and passing a reference to it to different go routines? Both routines can do a couple of `Get`,`Set` and `Del` operations.

I am not worried about the order of execution, but would it cause weird side effects, e.g. dropping calls to redis, or blocking too much if I create lots of go routines?

Alternatively, should I create one Client per go routine?

Same question would be for using a [kafka reader and writer](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go) .

Comment: The redis Client docs state: _”It's safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines”_, and the Kafka Client docs state: _”Clients are safe to use concurrently from multiple goroutines, as long as their configuration is not changed after first use”_. Both seem pretty clear.

Comment: I must have missed that, thank you. Links if anyone is interested:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jseparator/kafka-go#section-readme and https://github.com/redis/go-redis/blob/30a6f7107e9e633cef70b3b104aa1c6eb2db751b/redis.go#L587

Comment: The correct links for the docs would be [`kafka.Client`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/segmentio/kafka-go#Client) and [`redis.Client`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/redis/go-redis/v9#Client)